# how to drop rows by using query

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to drop rows based on query result but it gives me this error

```
  df2.drop(df.query('group == "treatment" and landing_page !="new_page" or group != "treatment" and landing_page =="new_page"'),axis=1)
```

the error shown is

```
ValueError: labels ['user_id' 'timestamp' 'group' 'landing_page' 'converted'] not contained in axis
```

Comment: If you want to drop rows it should be `axis=0`. It's hard to say more without a [MCVE]. Please share a sample dataframe and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `index` of `query` output with `axis=0` for rows as:

```
df2.drop(df.query('group == "treatment" and landing_page !="new_page" or group != "treatment" and landing_page =="new_page"').index, axis=0)
```